# How to build this complex Expression Func?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression

I'm currently working on an `EF` website where I have this database object:

```
public partial class Association
{
    public Association()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Association")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

An Item class:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.Associations = new HashSet<Association>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ItemTypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Item")]
    public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

And this dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<ItemTypeEnum, int> MaxOccupationRange = new Dictionary<ItemTypeEnum, int>()
    {
        { ItemTypeEnum.Type1, 1 },
        { ItemTypeEnum.Type2, 2 },
        { ItemTypeEnum.Type3, 5 },
        { ItemTypeEnum.Type4, 10 },
    };
```

I would need an `Expression<Func<Association, bool>>` that would return `true` if `association.Users.Count < MaxOccupationRange[association.Item.Type]`, and else `false`.
I think this should roughly look like the following method but unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with the `Expression` concept to achieve this kind of thing.

When debugging the following result, it seems like it computes (an not optimized but) correct expression.

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> MyExprMethod<TSource, TKey, TKey2, TValue>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey2>> source2, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        var body = dict
            .Aggregate((Expression)null, (next, dicEntry) => next == null
                ? Expression.Condition
                    (
                        Expression.LessThan(source2.Body, Expression.Constant(dicEntry.Value)),
                        Expression.Constant(true),
                        Expression.Constant(false)
                    )
                : Expression.Condition
                    (
                        Expression.Equal(source.Body, Expression.Constant(dicEntry.Key)),
                        Expression.Condition
                        (
                            Expression.LessThan(source2.Body, Expression.Constant(dicEntry.Value)),
                            Expression.Constant(true),
                            next
                        ),
                        next
                    )
                );

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, source.Parameters[0]);
    }
```

I try to call it this way:

```
var expr = MyHelper.MyExprMethod((Association x) => x.Item.Type, (Association b) => b.Users.Count, Item.MaxOccupationRange);
```

But obviously it complains about the `b` parameter to be unassigned since it does not appear in the result lambda.
I tried many things (anonymous type instead of two sources etc.) but it seems that I'm too unfamiliar with the concept, I could not find a way to generate such an expression.

Would anybody please show me ?

Thanks a lot.

***EDIT***

Here's the call context:

```
var filter = PredicateUtils.True<Association>();

var expr = MyHelper.MyExprMethod((Association x) => x.Item.Type, (Association b) => b.Users.Count, Item.MaxOccupationRange);
filter = filter.And(expr);

var associations = entities.Associations.Where(filter);
return associations .OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToPagedList(pageNb, 2);
```

And here's the message, shown on the last line (ToPagedList): `The parameter 'b' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression`

Comment: Where does it complain about b? The above code compiles and runs, *besides* `EF`.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I edited the first post hoping this helps

Comment: you want `Association x` and `Association b` to be the *same* parameter: have a look at my answer where I'm  showing how to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to [re-parametrize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541464/6996876) the second expression

```
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> MyExprMethod<TSource, TKey, TKey2, TValue>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey2>> source2, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        source2 = PredicateRewriter.Rewrite(source2, source.Parameters[0]);
        var body = dict
```

through a helper

```
    public class PredicateRewriter
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, U>> Rewrite<T,U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> exp, //string newParamName
            ParameterExpression param)
        {
            //var param = Expression.Parameter(exp.Parameters[0].Type, newParamName);
            var newExpression = new PredicateRewriterVisitor(param).Visit(exp);

            return (Expression<Func<T, U>>)newExpression;
        }
```

with a Visitor pattern

```
        private class PredicateRewriterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            private readonly ParameterExpression _parameterExpression;

            public PredicateRewriterVisitor(ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
            {
                _parameterExpression = parameterExpression;
            }

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            {
                return _parameterExpression;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, thank you so muh, you made my day ^^