# How to combine Expression<TDelegate> objects without invoking?

Tags: c#, delegates, expression, expression-trees

I have a `delegate` as follows:

```
public delegate TestResult TestCase(byte[] source);
```

...where the return `TestResult` is as follows:

```
public class TestResult {

    public bool Pass { get; }
    public int Index { get; }

    public TestResult(bool result, int index) {
        Pass = result;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

An example `TestCase` delegate looks like:

```
public static TestResult In(byte[] tkn, ITestSet testSet) {
    return testSet.Contains(tkn);
}
```

`ITestSet` is not much more than an encapsulated `HashSet<byte[]>`.

In one use case I have 2 test sets: (1) A - z, (2) 0 - 9. I want to test if an input `byte[]` is in either test set.

I am using `Expression<TestCase>` but having trouble figuring out how to implement the `Or` test case. I have a `TestCaseBuilder` with the following methods:

```
public class TestCaseBuilder {
    private Expression<TestCase> tcExpr;       

    public TestCaseBuilder With(TestCaseBuilder tcBuilder) {
        tcExpr = tcBuilder.tcExpr;
        return this;
    }

    public TestCaseBuilder Or(TestCaseBuilder tcBuilder) {
        tcExpr = tcExpr.Or(tcBuilder.tcExpr);        
        return this;
    }
}
```

...and my extension method:

```
public static Expression<TestCase> Or (this Expression<TestCase> tcLeft, Expression<TestCase> tcRight) {
    var lExpr = (LambdaExpression)tcLeft;
    var rExpr = (LambdaExpression)tcRight;    
    var param = lExpr.Parameters;

    return Expression.Lambda<TestCase>(/* what to do here ? */, param);
}
```

`Expression.OrElse` is mechanically what I would think is appropriate but cannot use that since I am returning a `TestResult`, not a `bool`.

Here is how the `TestCaseBuilder` is used:

```
testcaseBuilder.As("Foo")
    .With(isLetterTestCase)
    .Or(isDigitTestCase);
```

I have performed the `Or` using just the `TestCase` delegates:

```
public static TestCase Or(this TestCase tc1, TestCase tc2) {
    return tkn => {
        var res = tc1(tkn);
        if (res.Pass) {
            return res;
        }

        return tc2(tkn);
    };
}
```

How can I combine the 2 `Expression<TestCase>` in a custom `Or` method without invoking the first test case?

Comment: I think you'll need a custom ExpressionVisitor that is supplied the parameters to return upon visiting both expressions, returning a new one

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: may very well be ... I haven't used `ExpressionVisitor` yet so maybe someone will be able to provide a solution with that. This particular *test case* is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: It's very easy to write one. I'm on my cell phone as always so it's hard to write one. If you do a search for ParameterReplacer or ExpressionParamaterReplacer there is a post by Marc Gravell showing the usage.

Comment: Not the one I was thinking about, but there's an implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11160067/491907 I think you should only need to override `VisitParameter` in your case, but I might be wrong without actually trying it

Comment: See Marc's answer here at the bottom of his post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted

```
        public static Expression<Func<byte[], TestResult, TestCase, TestResult>> helperExp = (inp, res, next) => res.Pass ? next(inp) : res;

        public static Expression<TestCase> Or(Expression<TestCase> exp1, Expression<TestCase> exp2)
        {
            var param = exp1.Parameters;

            Expression<TestCase> or = Expression.Lambda<TestCase>(
               Expression.Invoke(helperExp,
                param[0], Expression.Invoke(exp1, param), exp2),param);

            return or;
        }
```

With a block expression no invoke

```
public static Expression<TestCase> Or(Expression<TestCase> exp1, Expression<TestCase> exp2)
        {
            var param = exp1.Parameters;

            ParameterExpression local = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TestResult), "local");

            BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
                new[] { local },
                Expression.Assign(local, exp1.Body),
                Expression.Condition(Expression.Property(local, nameof(TestResult.Pass)), exp2.Body, local));

            return Expression.Lambda<TestCase>(block, param);
        }
```

Test

```
            Expression<TestCase> exp1 = (tc) => new TestResult(true);
            Expression<TestCase> exp2 = (tc) => new TestResult(false);

            var first = Or(exp1, exp1);

            var second = Or(first, exp2);

            var func = second.Compile();

            var result = func(new byte[] { });
```

There might be a better way to do a conditional monad without expressions using https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad
I thing .net core uses the monad principle for middleware.

Comment: Without `Expression.Invoke` is the requirement.

Comment: @IAbstract But how can you know the result if you don't do an Invoke at some point?

Comment: @IAbstract made an edit to remove the invoke if it is still not what you wanted leave a comment and I will remove the answer.

Comment: @FilipCordas: I didn't want to invoke the expression when building the `Or` condition because there is no input at that point. The expression is built based on instructions for later input. Once the instruction is complete, the `Expression` will be compiled. Then later, input will be provided which the expression can test. Make sense?

Comment: @FilipCordas: great start and looks promising but there are two things - (1) it looks like this is actually an `And` evaluation since the `Condition` (on true) will go directly to the next evaluation rather than returning the `TestResult`. (2) I am getting an InvalidOperationException: **Additional information: variable 't' of type 'System.Byte[]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined**. I am trying to track this down now.

Comment: Okay, for the exception, looks like I need to back up to my base expressions and build those rather than using a lambda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30556993/210709

Comment: You are right this will do an and just switch the condition  Expression.Condition(Expression.Property(local, nameof(TestResult.Pass)), local, exp1.Body)

Comment: @IAbstract In regards to input parametars the delegate has a fix set of input prametars with a set of types I don't see how you could change the input parametas with out recreating whole set of expressions. Using Invoke makes no difference. Well I hope I helped a bit, if you find the whole solution could you post the answer since I am interested in how you did it.

Comment: I will. It looks like I was successful in creating the base Expression that replaces `t => t.In(testset)` delegate. When the expression is compiled, I have a compatible delegate `TestCase` which passes first unit tests. Once I've incorporated this answer with passing tests I'll post a solution with changes I had to make.

Comment: In case you need to reparametrize the second expression with the parameter from the first one,  this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041916/6996876) of mine could help maybe....